# How to write php if statement where mysql recordset result contain number

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I have a mysql database called menus. I am able to query my database to obtain a recordset accordingly. I do NOT want to write a query for each season. My problem: I want to write a php if statement within body to echo a message if the season field CONTAINS 2.

table menu

```
id | item (varcar)  | season (set)
1  | fresh lemonade | 2,3
2  | smoothie       | 2
3  | cafe latte     | 4
```

My query works fine

> mysql_select_db($database_rest, $rest); $query_menus = "SELECT * FROM
>   menus";
>
> $menus = mysql_query($query_menus, $rest) or die(mysql_error());
>
> $row_menus = mysql_fetch_assoc($menus);
>
> $totalRows_menus = mysql_num_rows($menus);

I can write a php if to work where recordset field = 2 that works.

```
<?php echo $row_menus['item']; ?>: <?php
      if (@$row_menus['season'] == 1)
        {
        echo "Winter";
        }
      else if (@$row_menus['season'] == 2)
        {
        echo "Spring";
        }
      else if (@$row_menus['season'] == 3)
        {
        echo "Summer";
        }
      else if (@$row_menus['season'] == 4)
        {
        echo "Fall";
        }
      ?>
```

Result Shows:

```
fresh lemonade: Spring
smoothie: Spring
cafe latte: Fall
```

I want to write php so that if season CONTAINS 2 (example: if (@$row_menus['season'] CONTAINS 1) echo Spring, etc for each. so that result would look like this:

```
fresh lemonade: Spring
fresh lemonade: Summer
smoothie: Spring
cafe latte: Fall
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you looking for a "switch" construct?

Comment: I am not looking to switch anything. I am wanting to show Winter if the season field contains 1, Spring if season field contains 2, Summer if season field contains 3, and Fall if season field contains 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's time to upgrade those `mysql_*` functions! Second, there's better ways to set up the relationship between the item and its seasons. However, I'll let you look into that stuff.

```
$query_menus = "SELECT * FROM menus";
$menus = mysql_query($query_menus, $rest) or die(mysql_error());

$seasons_array = array('All Seasons', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall');

while($row_menus = mysql_fetch_array($menus))
{
    $item = $row_menus['item'];
    $season = $row_menus['season'];

    if(strpos($season, ',') !== false)
    {
        $seasons = explode(',', $season);

        // To show the item and season on separate rows
        foreach($seasons as $s)
            echo $item . ': ' . trim($seasons_array[(int)$s]);

        // To show the item, and then a list of seasons
        echo $item . ': ';
        foreach($season as $k => $s)
            echo trim($seasons_array[(int)$s]) . (($k + 1) == count($season) ? '' : ', ');
    }
    else
    {
        echo $item . ': ' . $seasons_array[(int)$season];
    }
}
```

I didn't test this, but it should work for you. Try it out, and let us know.

EDIT: I updated it so that you can list the items on separate rows, or list the item followed by each season.

Comment: Please, do advice everybody to move on to `mysqli_*`

Comment: @iroegbu I did in my opening line. I suppose I could have been more specific, though. :)

Comment: I tried this. what it shows is a complete list of items but nothing for the season. I'm wondering how seasonal number (1) from the database gets translated into Winter, etc. on the page

Comment: That's where the `$seasons_array` comes into play. It uses the number from the database, and pulls the name from the array based on the number.

Comment: OK Kacey I think i get this. However, I still only get a list of items with : and nothing listing for actual season. Would i throw a wrench in this option if i have a season equal to 0 for "All Seasons"?

Comment: I've updated the code so that it should attempt to change your season value to an integer using `(int)`. Try that out.

Comment: Thanks Kacey. This Worked! Another question: If I wanted to show result like this... fresh lemonade: Spring, Summer?

Comment: @mvictor I've updated it so that you can choose which way you would like to go with the item list, as well as allowing for an 'All Season' option.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. use PHP to split the field into an array and work through that
2. use multiple rows where `season` only holds one value

Using PHP, you could use `$season=explode(',',$row_menus['season']);` and then use a `foreach` statement to iterate through `$season`

The problem you have is that PHP interprets `2,3` as a string. When it's converted into a number, it appears as `2`

Try using multiple rows for the `season` field:

```
id | item (varcar)  | season
1  | fresh lemonade | 3
2  | smoothie       | 2
3  | cafe latte     | 4
4  | fresh lemonade | 2
```

This will also help where you want to select all rows `where season=2`

Finally, as Tobias said, don't use the mysql_ functions. Use newer functions which are supported

Comment: Thanks DaveyBoy. Using multiple rows is not an option for me, as there are hundreds of menu items, and adding them multiple times for each season is just not an option.